# how to set timeout to google pubsub publisher and subscriber?

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, timeoutexception

In my java code I use Google -pubsub.

how can i set a timeout for

subscriber - wait for messages until timeout expires?
(how can i set a retry policy?)

publisher - wait till message is sent for `timeout` time.
(how can i set a retry policy?)

I saw this [post](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/980) but didn't manage to translate the js post to java

Here is how i set my sub

```
    final Subscriber subscriber = Subscriber
            .defaultBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver)
            .setChannelProvider(channelProvider)
            .build();
```

and pub

```
    final Publisher publisher = Publisher.defaultBuilder(topicName)
            .setChannelProvider(channelProvider)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

With the latest [Cloud Pub/Sub client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java), you do not need to set timeouts or retry policies in the Subscriber. These are handled under the hood for you and you just need to pass your [MessageReceiver](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.20.1/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/MessageReceiver.html) into [defaultBuilder](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.20.1/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.html#defaultBuilder-com.google.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionName-com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageReceiver-). When messages are available, they will be sent to [receiveMessage](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.20.1/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/MessageReceiver.html#receiveMessage-com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage-com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.AckReplyConsumer-). If your subscribing stops for any non-retryable reason, then the Subscriber will be shut down. You can listen for these notifications by calling [addListener](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/0.8.1/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/core/AbstractApiService.html#addListener-com.google.api.gax.core.ApiService.Listener-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) on your Subscriber.

On the Publisher, you can use [setRetrySettings](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.20.1/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Publisher.Builder.html#setRetrySettings-com.google.api.gax.retrying.RetrySettings-) in the Builder. In particular, you'd want to [setTotalTimeout](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/1.4.1/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/retrying/RetrySettings.Builder.html#setTotalTimeout-org.threeten.bp.Duration-) on RetrySettings.Builder. The Publisher will retry publish calls on retryable errors up to this total deadline.